# IsChanged with IChangeTracking Not Firing on Window Close WPF MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

My goal is to show a messagebox on a window if the user tries to close the window and changes have been made to the fields.  I am using wrappers to wrap the objects (inheriting the `NotifyDataErrorInfoBase` interface) that are represented on the screen, and all works fine when using command bindings and closing behaviors on the window closing events.

My problem is when the window first opens, a textbox has focus first.  If I type something into the textbox, and then click the "X" button to close the window, the track changes does not work.

If I type something into the textbox and then click my Close button (which is bound to a closing command), it works fine.

If I select a value from a dropdown and then click the "X" button to close the window, it works fine.

It seems that tracking changes only works when data is confirmed to a field when focus is lost on a field or another action is conducted, like a button click.  Is this true?  If so, is it possible to start tracking changes on `TextChanged`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the binding to `PropertyChanged`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding YourProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

This should cause the source property to get set immediately when you type something into the `TextBox`.